# Getting 0 as a value sending to my database during an AJAX call form submission

Tags: php, ajax, forms, prepared-statement

I am trying to send the user id and the value 'Approved' through the AJAX call to my prepared statement to send into my database. As of right now I am getting the id part of this correctly. However, the value for the Approved part is sending and updating my database as a 0.

Does anyone see why?

My Form

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if( $numrows ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            if($row['status'] == "Pending"){

                $pending_id        = $row['id'];
                $pending_user_id   = $row['user_id'];
                $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
                $pending_username  = $row['username'];
?>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="status">
             <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id'/>
<?php
        if ($pending_firstname == true) {
            echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . 
                "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>"
                //echo print_r($_POST);
?>


                        <button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Approve</button>
                        <button class="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Deny</button>
                        </form><br><br><br>
```

My AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.approve').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: $(this).val(), //id
                status: 'Approved' //status
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $("#success").fadeIn();
                $("#success").show();
                $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
                $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
            },
            //type: 'POST'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

My Prepared Statement

```
$pending_id = $_POST['id'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE user_requests SET status=?, date_responded=NOW() WHERE id=?");
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User Request update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $status, $pending_id);
    // comment added by php-dev : should be false === $stmt->bind_param ...

    if ( false===$stmt ) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Request update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    // comment added by php-dev : should be false === $stmt->execute ... 
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
        die('User Status update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

By ajax form you are providing "status" as string with value "Approved" to server while you are assuming it integer in binding. Just change "status" in ajax code to '1'

Comment: Based on your answer I figured it out. I had to make my prepared statement params 'si' and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answer it clicked what I was doing wrong. I had my php parameters set as both being integer when it needed to be 'si' not 'ii'.